# Maven hive-exec conflicts with protobuf

Tags: maven, hive, protocol-buffers

I'm a newbie of maven. In my project, I find that the hive-exec is conflicting with protobuf. Below is the pom in my project.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.0.2.1.7.0-784</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So I dig deeper into the `hive-exec`. I find that it's using a maven-shade-plugin. I guess it's for packaging the hive-exec jar. Below is the related code in the hive-exec.pom:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>build-exec-bundle</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactSet>
            <includes>
              ...
              <include>com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java</include>
              ...
            </includes>
          </artifactSet>
          <relocations>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>com.esotericsoftware</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

And also (I'm not sure how the profile works):

```
<profile>
  <id>protobuf</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-protobuf-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <property />
                <property />
                <echo>Building ORC Protobuf</echo>
                <mkdir />
                <exec>
                  <arg />
                  <arg />
                  <arg />
                </exec>
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Here is a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4156) should be related.

My question is:

1. How can I exclude the built in protobuff, and override the class with the protobuff 3.1.0? Looks like a normal `<excludes>` won't work in this case.
2. If I can't override it, how can I find the version of the protobuff class? I couldn't find it in the hive-exec.pom.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Putting the proto-buff dependency in front of the hive-exec resolved the conflict! Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770549/java-override-class-to-load-project-class-instead-jar-class. I'm still open with other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

hive-exec also has a core classifier for this .jar. Here's how I resolved this problem in Gradle, Maven provides a `<classifier>` tag you should be able to use.

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.hive', name: 'hive-exec', version: '3.1.2', classifier: 'core'
```

This version doesn't have the other dependencies in their goofy non-shaded .jar to muck up your classpath, and it resolved things for me when I ran into a similar problem.

Comment: It works for me, what does classifier: 'core' mean and does?

Answer (score 1):

Putting protobuf-java before hive-exec works for me:

```
<!-- protobuf-java should come before hive-exec -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
  <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
  <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Omfg! Thank you so much, I did not know maven dependencies are order sensitive.